# Inserir vários valores numa tabela

Tags: sql

Como é que faço para inserir vários valores numa tabela, mas numa única **query** de  **sql**?

Comment: Qual seria o `SGDB`?

Comment: SGBD significa Sistema de Gerenciamento de Base de Dados só para o caso de não saberes :/ por exemplo MySQL é um SGBD

Answer (score 9):

#### SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MariaDB, DB2 e MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO TESTE VALUES (1,'ABACAXI'), (2,'BATATA');
```

Exemplos:

- `SQL Server` no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/32e8b/1).
- `MySQL` no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d19f/1).
- `PostgreSQL` no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6bb58/2).

#### Oracle:

Pode utilizar o [`INSERT ALL`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm#i2125362):

```
INSERT ALL
   INTO TESTE VALUES (1,'ABACAXI')
   INTO TESTE VALUES (2,'BATATA')
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Veja em funcionamento no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/33abc/1).

#### MongoDB

```
db.teste.insert([
    {"id": 1, nome: "ABACAXI"},
    {"id": 2, nome: "BATATA"}
]);
```

---

<sub>Como não informou o SGDB coloquei os principais, se não for o caso, eu atualizo depois.</sub>

Comment: Já agora, mariaDB, postgres e nosql :)

Answer (score 0):

Com Sql Server, 2 sugestões:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set @sql = N'insert into tabela (coluna1, coluna2) values (''coluna1'', ''coluna2'');
             insert into tabela (coluna1, coluna2) values (''coluna1'', ''coluna2'');
             insert into tabela (coluna1, coluna2) values (''coluna1'', ''coluna2'');'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

ou

```
insert into tabela (coluna1, coluna2)
select coluna1, coluna2 from tabela2
```